# XML to SelectList using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, selectlistitem

I am attempting to get a Select List from an XML string...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selectListItemDefinition id="UPMCTypes">
  <item key="bla1" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla2" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla3" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla4" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla5" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla6" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla7" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla8" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla9" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla10" value="bla" />
  <item key="bla11" value="bla" />
</selectListItemDefinition>
```

That would be the XML string that I am trying to turn into a SelectList
Here is how I am trying to do it...

```
List<SelectListItem> SListItem =
(
    from xmlSList in xDoc.Descendants("selectListItemDefinition")
    let listItem = xmlSList.Elements("item")
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Key = xmlSList.Attribute("key").Value,
        Value = xmlSList.Attribute("value").Value
    }
).ToList();
```

This only gets the first Key-Value one for me.

```
Key    "blah1"  string
Value  "blah"   string
```

Now I think it's because I am only getting one Element here?  But I am not sure what I would do to get this right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a problem in your query, as you should be getting an exception.

You are trying to select the attributes "key" and "value" of `<selectListItemDefinition>`, but they don't exist.  And you are not actually using `listItem` in your select clause.

Your first line is returning an `IEnumerable<XElement>` of all nodes called "selectListItemDefinition".  Your second line is just taking that `IEnumerable<>` and assigning the child elements called "item" it to variable named `listItem`.

When you should be doing is a second query to iterate over the `<selectListItemDefinition>` elements instead of assigning it.

So replace `let listItem = xmlSList.Elements("item")` with `from listItem in xmlSList.Elements("item")` and it should behave as you expect.

the full query would be:

```
var SListItem = 
                (
                    from xmlSList in xDoc.Descendants("selectListItemDefinition")
                    from listItem in xmlSList.Elements("item")
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Key = listItem .Attribute("key").Value,
                        Value = listItem .Attribute("value").Value
                    }
                ).ToList();
```

And if you are 100% certain that the only elements called `<item>` in your XML document are the ones you want, you can replace the first and second lines with a single one `from listItem in xDoc.Descendants("item")` and you will get the same behavior.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up doing something similar.  This linq to xml is a real bear.